# How to connect Dremel 3D45 to a hidden WiFi network?

Tags: dremel-3d45, wi-fi

At office we have a hidden WiFi network. I'm not able to connect our Dremel 3D45 to this network, since when you tap on "WiFi" it scans for the available networks and it does not add the "Hidden network" item as usual.

I also tried to make the network visible for a while. Then I connected the 3D printer, but as soon as the network hides the SSID (even without bringing down the AP) the printer disconnects immediately.

Was anyone able to connect to a hidden network on Dremel 3D45?

Unfortunately, I cannot ask the IT to change this settings permanently.

Comment: Is this a work related use? Does the IT dept know you are wanting to connect this? The IT dept should be able to get this thing connected. "hidden" simply means it is not broadcasting the SSID. If you know the SSID and password, it should connect, hidden or otherwise.

Comment: @WPNSGuy have you ever tried to connect the Dremel 3D45 to a hidden network? I'm aware what is it, but I don't know *how* to do on this printer!

Comment: @WPNSGuy I mean, the question is not about networking in general, but is related to this model of 3D printer